# Withings authorization

Tags: java, oauth, withings

I've got a problem with getting User Data Access Token from the Withings API (step 3 of the api doc):
http://oauth.withings.com/api/doc#api-OAuth_Authentication-access_token

Service returns "Invalid signature" error.

Here is my methods:

```
private static String getSignature(String url, String params, String authSecret) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    StringBuilder base = new StringBuilder();
    base.append("GET&");
    base.append(url);
    base.append("&");
    base.append(params);

    byte[] keyBytes;
    if (authSecret != null) {
        keyBytes = (secret + "&" + authSecret + "&").getBytes(ENC);
    } else {
        keyBytes = (secret + "&").getBytes(ENC);
    }

    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, HMAC_SHA1);

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1);
    mac.init(key);
    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    return new String(base64.encode(mac.doFinal(base.toString().getBytes(ENC))), ENC).trim();
}
public static AuthResponse getAccessToken(AuthRequest request) {
    try {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        String url = "https://oauth.withings.com/account/access_token";
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(url);
        List<NameValuePair> valuePairs = new ArrayList<>();

        valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_key", key));
        valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_nonce", "" + (int) (Math.random() * 100000000)));
        valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1"));
        valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_timestamp", "" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)));
        valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token", request.getOauthToken()));
        valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_version", "1.0"));
        valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", request.getUserId()));

        String signature = getSignature(URLEncoder.encode(url, ENC), URLEncoder.encode(URLEncodedUtils.format(valuePairs, ENC), ENC), request.getOauthTokenSecret());

        valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature", signature));

        builder.addParameters(valuePairs);

        URI uri = builder.build();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String result;

        while ((result = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(result);
        }

        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("*Error during getAccessToken request");
    }
}
```

I also tried without "authSecret" parameter to generate signature (like in withings specification), tried to change order and place "oauth_signature" parameter alphabetically, **but I had no success** 
Can anyone help me?
PS: at the previous two steps of the Api Documentation I successfully got the oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, userid using this signature generator.

Comment: Can you try [this](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava), instead of implementing your own OAuth solution? They even have a [pull request](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/pull/527/files) for your site, which you can copy and use.

Comment: @user3707125 ThanX a lot, the authorization works fine. I successfully got data from the Withings "playground" with received access and secret tokens. But this oauth implementation has 2 problems: it is unavailable from maven central with version 2.0 and when I tried to get data (body measurements) like in example, I got empty response body with status:2554 (Wrong action or wrong webservice).

Comment: What am I doing wrong? `OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://wbsapi.withings.net/measure?action=getmeas", service);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();

        return response.getBody();`

Comment: I fixed it adding the ".signatureType(SignatureType.QueryString)" to OAuthService.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get STEP3 working, you've got to remove the second "&" from the line:

```
keyBytes = (secret + "&" + authSecret + "&").getBytes(ENC);
```

so it becomes:

```
keyBytes = (secret + "&" + authSecret).getBytes(ENC);
```